# Explicit instantiation for All derived-classes

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation

I have a `Component` class:

```
class Component 
{

}
```

Then a `Collider` class that inherits from it:

```
class Collider :public Component
{

}
```

And a `SphereCollider` that inherits from the `Collider`:

```
class SphereCollider :public Collider
{

}
```

Finally,a `GameObject` class that you can use add or remove components to.

The *GameObject.h* header:

```
class GameObject
{
    //Add functionality
    template <class T>
    T& AddComponent();

    //Get functionality
    template <typename T>
    T& GetComponent();
}
```

The *GameObject.cpp* source:

```
template <typename T>
T& GameObject::AddComponent(){}

template <typename T>
T& GameObject::GetComponent(){}

//Explicit instantiation 
template Component &GameObject::GetComponent<Component>();
template Component &GameObject::AddComponent<Component>();
template SphereCollider &GameObject::GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
template SphereCollider &GameObject::AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
```

Everything is working fine. I can Add or Get component from a GameObject without pointer like below:

```
GameObject gameObject;
SphereCollider sCollider1 = gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();
SphereCollider sCollider2 = gameObject.GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
Component sCollider3 = gameObject.GetComponent<Component>();
```

**Problem:**

I need to use this as a library and hide the source file. Since I added explicit instantiation for the `Component` and `SphereCollider` classes in the *GameObject.cpp* source, only those can compile.

For example,

```
Collider sCollider = gameObject.GetComponent<InnoEngine::Collider>();
```

will not compile unless I also add:

```
template Collider &GameObject::GetComponent<Collider>();
template Collider &GameObject::AddComponent<Collider>();
```

in the the *GameObject.cpp* source.

*Since everything that uses the `GetComponent` and `AddComponent` functions inherits from  the `Component` class, is there a way to automatically make Explicit instantiation for every class that inherits from the `Component` class?*

I tried `template Component &GameObject::GetComponent<Component>();`
 and `template Component &GameObject::AddComponent<Component>();` but that didn't work and only gave me the *"unresolved external symbol"* error.

The only option I have at this moment is to put all the template functions in the header file but that will expose an important code for both `GetComponent` and `AddComponent` template functions.

Comment: It's not obvious why you need to use templates to do this, or why code to add or get components should need to be hidden.

Comment: @NeilButterworth - Presumably for the nice (opinion based) uniform syntax of `Get<Thing>`

Comment: @NeilButterworth I need to use template because I am shooting for a particular syntax like this `gameObject.AddComponent<SphereCollider>()` just like [Unity Engine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html)  C# but for C++. I don't think there is another way to get that syntax without template.

Comment: @StoryTeller That's right. I just want those that have used Unity but program with C++ to be able to use it or port their code to C++ easily.

Comment: @Programmer There is no way of knowing the full list of derived classes. However, could you specify the relevant `GetComponent` and `AddComponent` instantiations at the end of the implementation file of each component sub-type?

Comment: Nope. The `GetComponent` and `AddComponent` functions needs to be in the `GameObject` and the `Component` classes. You cannot and should not have to implement them in the each derived components. All the user has to make their class inherit from the `Component` class.

Comment: @Programmer Then no. You essentially want to generate new instances of a function template without the source code. You either need to provide ever instances of the template the user will ever need, or you need to provide the source code for their compiler to complete the missing instances.

Comment: I was afraid of that answer. I can remove the template if there is another way to get that exact syntax but I don't think so. Thanks for your replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since everything that uses the `GetComponent` and `AddComponent` functions inherits from the `Component` class, is there a way to automatically make Explicit instantiation for every class that inherits from the `Component` class?

The short answer is "No".

Deriving a class from `Component` accomplishes exactly that. You get a derived class -- nothing else and nothing more. If the base class has `virtual` member functions that are overridden in the derived class, you get the behavior implemented in the derived class.

Anything additional has to be coded up. The amount of additional code that needs to written depends on the additional functionality and the framework that you provide to facilitate that.

Here's one possible way to accomplish your goal. Please note that this uses `dynamic_cast`, which may fail if you are not careful.

```
class Component 
{
   public:
      virtual ~Component() {}
};

#include <map>

// Implement GameObject with no knowledge of any of the classes derived 
// from Component. That will be one sure fire way of making sure that it can
// be used for any class derived from Component.

class GameObject
{
   public:

    //Add functionality
    template <class T>
    T& AddComponent()
    {
       T* obj = new T{};
       AddComponent(getTypeID<T>(), obj);
       return *obj;
    }

    //Get functionality
    template <typename T>
    T& GetComponent()
    {
       T* obj = dynamic_cast<T*>(GetComponent(getTypeID<T>()));
       return *obj;
    }

   private:

    // If necessary, the implementation can be moved to a .cpp file.
    void AddComponent(int typeID, Component* obj)
    {
       components[typeID] = obj;
    }

    // If necessary, the implementation can be moved to a .cpp file.
    Component* GetComponent(int typeID)
    {
       return components[typeID];
    }

    // Key function.
    // It gets a unique integer for every type.
    template <class T>
       static int getTypeID()
       {
          static int typeID = getNextID();
          return typeID;
       }

    // If necessary, the implementation can be moved to a .cpp file.
    static int getNextID()
    {
       static int nextID = 0;
       return ++nextID;
    }

    std::map<int, Component*> components;
};

class Collider : public Component
{
};

class SphereCollider :public Collider
{
};

int main()
{
   GameObject go;
   go.AddComponent<Collider>();
   go.AddComponent<SphereCollider>();

   Collider c = go.GetComponent<Collider>();
   SphereCollider sc = go.GetComponent<SphereCollider>();
}
```

Comment: I already have the `T& AddComponent()` and `T& GetComponent()` functions implemented with `dynamic_cast` and a mechanism that makes sure that both functions can never return `null` since both functions returns reference. I am just looking for a way to hide the long code inside them.

Comment: I hate un-accepting and accepting another answer but your answer is what I am looking for. It has a workaround I can use to hide the long code with `AddComponent(int typeID, Component* obj)`. Thanks

Comment: @Programmer, glad to hear I was able to help.

Answer (score 5):

No, it's impossible.

1) `template Component &GameObject::GetComponent<Component>()` is an explicit instantiation only for a concrete `Component` class. Compiler doesn't find definitions of the pure virtual methods and so you get linker error.

2) Some classes derived from `Component` can be inaccessible in GameObject.cpp if you don't add corresponding include. So in general case compiler even theoretically can't get the list of all the inheritors, because this information is available only at the linkage time.